# Why django admin sometimes uses some field of the model in the index, instead of __unicode__ method?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

For some of my models, Django-admin, in the index of the model's objects, instead of displaying the output of the `__unicode__` method like normally, it just displays one of the model's fields there.

This happens usually when there is something like:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

in my model, then the value of the field `name` is displayed (even though there is also a `__unicode__` method), but not always, sometimes it just displays what `__unicode__` says even if there is a class Meta ordering.

All my Unicode methods are quite normal, something like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'[%s] %s' % (self.field, self.name, )
```

I am puzzled, why is a field used sometimes instead of `__unicode__`, and how can I make it use the `__unicode__` method always? This is Django 1.3. Is this a bug in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the fields displayed in the django admin using the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option in your `ModelAdmin` class.

The model `__unicode__` method, and the `Meta.ordering` option do not have any affect on the fields displayed.

If you do not set `list_display`, then the default behaviour is to display a single column with the unicode string for each object.

If the unicode string is not displayed for your model, it sounds like you have set `list_display`. For example, to display the name field instead of the unicode string, you would do:

```
class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
```

If you want to display the unicode string *and* other fields, simply include `__unicode__` in `list_display`.

```
class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [`__unicode__`, 'name']
```